# defining static variable inside a function in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am taking first steps in agularJS and got stuck trying to create a static variable in a function. the function gets a variable called `cron_format` and i want the function to save that value. thee function checks if user changed the value of cron_format and if so, posts the data. 
this is the function:

```
   $scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat,letter,comp,index){

        //split cronFormat to match the value in the table, and than save changes
        var newCron =  $scope.split(cronFormat);
        newCron[index] = letter;

        //remove commas to match the cron's format
        newCron = newCron.toString().replace(/,/g, " ");

        if(letter!=comp) {
            $.post("updateCronChange.php", "user_id=" + userId + "&script_id=" + scriptId + "&cron_format=" + newCron, function (data) {
                console.log("cron changed to: "+newCron);
            });
        }
    }
```

i want to store the variable `newCron` so that next time function being called, cronFormat will be equal to newCron from last execution...any help plz?

Comment: This isn't really your "first steps" in angularJS, you have at least a dozen questions over the last week all related to this `saveCron` script, and identical sounding questions with identical variable names under 2 other user accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that the function "closes over" the outer scope variables, and create one to store your previous value.

```
var prevCron; // Define a variable to hold the value between function calls.

$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat,letter,comp,index){

    //split cronFormat to match the value in the table, and than save changes
    var newCron =  $scope.split(cronFormat);
    newCron[index] = letter;

    //remove commas to match the cron's format
    newCron = newCron.toString().replace(/,/g, " ");

    if(letter!=comp) {
        $.post("updateCronChange.php", "user_id=" + userId + "&script_id=" + scriptId + "&cron_format=" + newCron, function (data) {
            console.log("cron changed to: "+newCron);
        });
    }

    // Use the outer variable to store our current value.
    prevCron = newCron;
}
```